# Error C2533: Constructors not allowed a return type

Tags: c++, templates

Why does it show an error?

and why can't I use a return type?

This is the part of the code where the error exists

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{ 
public:
   Matrix(int x = default_x, int y = default_y);
   ~Matrix();
   Matrix<T> Matrix(const Matrix<T>& src);
   int get_x_size() const { return x_size; }
   int get_y_size() const { return y_size; }
   T get_element(int x, int y) const;
   void set_element(int x, int y, T elem);
   // constant elements
  static const int default_x = 3;
  static const int default_y = 3;
protected:
   T** cells;
   int x_size;
   int y_size;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Matrix<T> Matrix(const Matrix<T>& src);
```

The error tells you what is wrong. A constructor may not have a return type, just remove the `Matrix<T>` return type.

Edit: regarding WHY you can't use a return type you can, for example, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356109/c-constructors-have-no-return-type-just-exactly-why)